# how to call open native app in mobile by click button in sencha app

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch-2, sencha-touch-2.1

i have to develop an application in sencha touch which can support for various application with in a application(many in one). i have redirected it in sencha app to any of the view but i need that "by clicking the one button" that can be need to open another application in mobile(like google play, games,etc).
googlebook: function(){
    var googlebook=Ext.create('sample.view.NoBuses');

},

note:
instead of this (sample.view.NoBuses) in need to open another native app

Comment: Its not possible you cant open native application, using web application..

Comment: Pretty sure Moath is correct - but you can if your Sencha app is packaged natively. Not quite sure if you clarified that in your question.